# Responsive HTML5 CSS using media queries creating different video settings for different screen sizes

Tags: css, html, video

I want to have 2 different videos in my responsive site, one should display on PC screens and the other one on screen sizes under 1025px. The reason I have to do this is because I want the video to autoplay on PCs but autoplay is not available on mobile devices so for mobile I have to add controls and remove the autoplay from the html.

So here is my current code with one video only for all screen sizes, not set to autoplay for the reason above. My question is how can I change this code in the CSS media queries to have 2 videos with different settings: 1 with autoplay for PC screens and 1 with a player for mobile screens. My current code below works fine, displaying the video on all devices with conjtrols in a player. I only have 1 CSS stylesheet file separated with this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 1025px)
```

The html:

```
<div class="videoScreen">

        <video src="video/somevideo.mp4" controls="controls"></video>

    </div>
```

The CSS above the @media

```
.videoScreen video {
    width:99.8%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0.5% 0 0 0;

}
```

The CSS below the @media

```
.videoScreen video {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 3% 0% 0% 0%;


    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but if your current code works, then what exactly is your query?

Comment: @JasonNathan in my question I explained that I want to have the video on autoplay on PCs and play with controls on mobile screens. This is not what happens now.

Comment: are you controlling the video playback with javascript? could you post some code?

Comment: @JasonNathan no I am not using Javascript for the player, actually my aim is not to have a player on PCs just autoplay with no controls and on mobile just use the simple player.

Comment: unless im mistaken, and from what i remember, ios devices do not support any autoplay, i know you are looking for code to give you autoplay controls on ios but that happens automatically. the video will just show up paused, the user clicks the still frame and the video plays...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

*Note: I have left out the extra BootstrapCSS code that actually adjust the size and location of each and which video shows.*

**HTML for Large:**

```
<video id="large-video" class="embed-responsive-item" controls>
        <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**HTML for Small:**

```
<video id="small-video" class="embed-responsive-item" controls>
        <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 1025) {
    $('#large-video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
  } else {
    $('#small-video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The auto play isn't really a css issue. You could either use javascript/ jquery to alter the html of the video tag based on screen size-

```
 if (  $(window).width() > 1025px ) {
$(‘.videoScreen’).html(‘whatever your autoplay html is’);
}
```

Comment: autoplay is not my problem, my question is regarding media queries

Comment: I can try the javascript/jquery solution you offered, can you pls show how the whole code would look like? What do I put exactly in the ('whatever your autoplay html is')

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing would be to just rewrite the iframe for the video, changing the auto play setting.

```
 if (  $(window).width() > 1025px ) {
$(‘.videoScreen’).html(‘<iframe width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/R95V8u9ZQAw?vq=hd720&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=2&amp;rel=0&amp;color=white" frameborder="0" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%;"></iframe>’);
}
```

Ideally, instead of setting this based on the screen width, you could do a feature detection for a touch device.

http://modernizr.com can help with that.